# client validation of user control without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with two user controls inside two different ajax updatepanels. One control has textboxes and other control has a button. I have set same validation group to both user control's control's. When I hit the button, client validation fires but there is a potback after validation fires.

I have set validationgroup like this:

```
 public string ValidationGroup
        {
            get
            {
                return txtFirstName.ValidationGroup;
            }
            set
            {
                txtFirstName.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtLastName.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtPhoneNumber.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtEmail.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtFaxNumber.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtCompany.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtAddress1.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtAddress2.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtCity.ValidationGroup = value;
                txtZipPostalCode.ValidationGroup = value;
            }
        }

and here is how first control is user with validation group set to that property:

 <nopCommerce:AddressEdit ID="ctrlBillingAddress" runat="server" IsNew="true" IsBillingAddress="true"
                        ValidationGroup="CheckoutConfirm" />

and here is how the control with button looks like:

 <nopCommerce:CheckoutConfirm ID="ctrlCheckoutConfirm" runat="server" OnePageCheckout="true"
                                        OnCheckoutStepChanged="ctrlCheckoutConfirm_CheckoutStepChanged" />

where as markup for the button is like this:

 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnNextStep" 
                    OnClick="btnNextStep_Click" ValidationGroup="CheckoutConfirm" CausesValidation="true"><img src="App_Themes/darkOrange/images/btnPlaceOrder.png" alt="Place Order" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

Please suggest how to do client validation without postback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the updatemode on your update panels set to ?

See [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1572520.aspx) on asp.net forums. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for this write:

```
function check(){
if (Page_ClientValidate('validationgroup')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
}
```

Also try to debug your complete code in chrome may be you also have bug in some line.